# Non-volatile "variables" in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I was wondering if there is a way to have some sort of database-wide "variables" in postgresql, that is, some sort of persistent value stored in the database that can be used from the various functions or views of the database, for example, giving me the ability to change that one value to reflect the necessary changes to all the entities using it.

One primitive way to achieve that would be to create a function that always returns a pre-defined value, that way acting as a constant. Is there a better way to achieve that? I feel this purpose is not well implemented with a normal sql table, because it would better be matched by a key-value like structure.

Comment: You can store such variables in a global `parameters` table and then use the table to access them in any query that needs them.

Comment: So in a way like "SELECT * FROM user_data.parameters WHERE parameter_name = 'name' ;" ? What if the variables were of different types?

Comment: I think think the "function per constant" would be a good solution. Make sure the function is a `language sql` function and is marked as `immutable` so that it can be inlined

Comment: [Global Values in PL/Perl](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/plperl-global.html)